# React Hooks: Passing a parameter to a custom Hook to dynamically set API request query

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, react-hooks

I have experience with React but I am very new to using Hooks. I'm working on a project that retrieves stats from the NHL API. I am building a site that allows users to view hockey stats by team. I have my project set up with `React-Router` so that each team's stats page is the team name i.e. `/rangers` is the New York Rangers page, `/capitals` is the Washington Capitals page, etc...

The NHL API's endpoint for team stats looks like this `https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/3/roster` . The number after `teams` represents which team you are searching for. `3` in this query represents the New York Rangers endpoint. I have created an object to store team names and their associated number for the API request, like this:

```
const teams = {
    devils: {
        id: 1
    },
    islanders: {
        id: 2
    },
    rangers: {
        id: 3
    }
}
```

I plan on using [useLocation](https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/) to grab the team name from the URL, look up it's associated number in the above object, and then pass that number to an `axios` get request URL to retrieve that team's stats.

For example, the user goes to the Islanders page at `/islanders` in my project, I then use `useLocation` to grab `/islanders` from the URL, then I look up the Islanders ID in the object and find `2`. I then want to pass the `2` to an `axios` GET request like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teamID}/roster`)
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data.roster);
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error : ' + err);
            })
    }, []);
```

How can I pass a `teamID` variable to the `axios` request? I have tried the following:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const classes = useStyles();

// Get URL from team page user is on
const location = useLocation();
//  '/islanders'
const teamWithSlash = location.pathname;
// Removes /    '/islanders' becomes 'islanders'
const team = teamWithSlash.slice(1, teamWithSlash.length);

useEffect((team) => {
    axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teams.${team}.id}/roster`)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data.roster);
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error : ' + err);
        })
}, []);
```

I've also tried building a custom Hook that would allow me to pass a `teamID` parameter to it but I couldn't figure out how to make that work. I can access the number I need to pass to the `axios` request but can't figure out how to dynamically pass it to `useEffect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the argument from useEffect. `team` value can be obtained from the enclosing closure.

Also use square brackets to access dynamic object properties.

```js
useEffect(() => { 
   axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teams[team].id}/roster`)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data.roster);
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error : ' + err);
        })
}, []);
```